How to adjust vertical spacing after a tall equation
This MWE
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}
    
    The \verb=\hrule= after this equation is fine: 
    \begin{equation*}
        x + y = z.
    \end{equation*}
    \hrule
    
    \vskip 0.5in
    
    But the \verb=\hrule= after this equation isn't vertically spaced the same as in the previous example:
    \begin{equation*}
        x = \frac{1}{y}.
    \end{equation*}
    \hrule

\end{document}

produces this:

I guess that LaTeX uses the center line of an equation to determine where the following line should be placed?
At any rate, my question is how do I tell LaTeX to place the \hrule exactly 1 \baselineskip below the lowest point of the preceding equation?  I realize that the default behavior is usually how you want it, but in the document I'm creating this problem is exaggerated and it looks bad.

Vertical space around   equations are sensitive on the length of text line above equation.  If Their lengths is small (enough), than for space is considered \abovedisplayshortskip and \belowdisplayshortskip, which are smaller than \abovedisplayskip and \belowdisplayskip used at longer text line. To prove this, try to make those text lines equal length and than see obtained result.
